# Is there a way to prove that this example of a hascode algorithm will give unique values

Tags: hashtable, unique, hashcode

I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPo-M8bzRrc&index=21&list=PL4BBB74C7D2A1049C,(CS 61B Lecture 21: Hash Tables) and the example the professor gave was

You have a two letter word, each letter falls between  a-z

```
public class Word{
      public static final int LETTERS = 26, WORDS = LETTERS * LETTERS;
      private String word;
      public int hashCode(){
            return LETTERS * (word.charAt(0)-'a') + word.charAt(1) - 'a';
      }
}
```

Is there a way to prove(mathematical?) that each possible word will map to a different value between 0 and 675?
I've proved that the range will be between 0 and 675(give "aa" and "zz", but unsure about how to prove uniqueness.

Comment: You mean any possible word? It's pretty easy to prove the opposite, by giving a counter example: 'aaa' will have the same hash code as 'aab'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to get the hash code is:

```
hash = 26 * (A - 'a') + (B - 'a')
     = 26 * (A - 97)  + (B - 97)     // 'a' == 97 in ASCII
     = 26A + B - 27*97
```

So what we need to prove is that `26A + B` has distinct values for any A and B in range `<97; 122>` (decimal values for `<'a'; 'z'>`). We ignore the constant `27 * 97 part, as it would not change the reasoning.

Let's look at the opposite statement - when the hash code would not be distinct? It would not be distinct when change in `A` would be compensated by the change in `B`. So the following would need to be true:

```
26 * A1 + B1 = 26 * A2 + B2
```

Let's assume that `A2 = A1 + 1`:

```
26 * A1 + B1 = 26 * (A1 + 1) + B2
             = 26 * A1 + B2 + 26
```

Which means:

```
B1 = B2 + 26
B1 - B2 = 26
```

Which is impossible, because B is the char code for letters in range <'a'; 'z'>. And this range, in decimal ASCII values, is 25 (122-97). The required compensation by B would increase for every other A1 - A2 difference.

So, by proving the opposite is impossible, we've proved that hash code is unique for that characters.